# MenuPicker Sort when selected SwiftUI

Tags: swift, sorting, swiftui, menu, picker

Im trying to select one of sort in menu and sending backend . But somehow onTapGesture is not triggered. I also tried to use button but it didn't work either. Or is there any other way to trigger any of sort In menu picker.

```
var sortMenuPicker : some View {
    
    HStack(alignment: .center){
        
        Spacer()
        
        Picker(selection: $selection, label: SortView().frame(height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.050), content: {
            ForEach(sortListArray, id: \.uid, content: { item in
                ForEach(item.sortList ?? [],id:\.uid) { data in
                    
                    if item.id == "sort" {
                        
                        Text(data.name ?? "")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                
                                sortId = data.id
                                
                                getProductList()
                                
                                
                      }
                            
                    }
                    
                }
                
            })
        })
        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
```

[image]

Comment: which type is for selection var?

Comment: I would have thought you needed to modify a @State variable to trigger a refresh of the UI.

Comment: var selection = UUID()

Answer (score 0):

Add a tag to your `Text()` and remove Tap Gesture.

```
Text(data.name ?? "").tag(data.uid) //<-- Here
```

And use onReceive to listen to your selection

```
.onReceive(Just(selection)) { (_) in
    print(selection)
}
```

Note: for this you need to `import Combine`

Comment: it didn't work actually . and I have to say every sort has a id which represent data.id so I have to send data.id to server and it gives me new list of product.And I should request every time when user click different sort type.

Comment: Then you should use id for selection or you can just find id from UUID.

Comment: How can I find id from UUID I couldn't find a solution. I can get UUID for each sort type when I select in Menu .